# Unable to get form value in controller in yii

Tags: php

I am learning YII and I am stuck with a problem.I am trying to make a form but I am unable to get the values from the form in my controller. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
This is my

**(model) Logindetails.php**

```
class Logindetails extends CActiveRecord {             
public $pass;
    //rest of the coding

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('password', 'length', 'max'=>20),
    );
}
```

**(view) _form.php**

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'logindetails-form',
)); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pass'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'pass',array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>20)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'pass'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**controller**

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $model=new Logindetails;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Logindetails'])) {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Logindetails'];
        if(isset($model->pass)) {
            echo 'its present';
        } else {
            echo 'its absent';
        }

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

It keeps on showing me **it's absent**. Why I am having this problem?

Comment: instead of echo try die($_POST['Logindetails']['pass'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above code you just change your condition in controller.

```
if(isset($model->pass))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['Logindetails']['pass']))

OR

if($model->pass != ""))
```

You may debug your code to check either the value of text field is coming or not.

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $model=new Logindetails;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Logindetails'])) {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Logindetails'];

        print_r($model->attributes); //check either the values are coming or not.

        echo $model->pass ;

        exit; // finish here the program.

        if(isset($model->pass)) {
            echo 'its present';
        } else {
            echo 'its absent';
        }

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**(model) Logindetails.php**

You must add rules,

```
class Logindetails extends CActiveRecord {             
public $pass;

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('password', 'length', 'max'=>20),
        **array('pass', 'length', 'max'=>20),**
    );
}
```

After adding , You check `$model->pass` value is receiving in controller.